# Until how many pixels should i do responsive the web page?

Tags: html, css

I a making a web page locally on my computer on google chrome. I click inspect and i start resizing the window and there is value in the right corner telling me the current pixels of the window. when should i stop making the web Page responsive, until what pixels? Is there any rule of thumb?
Thank you.

Comment: Your question is very broad but it depends on whom you are targeting your website for. You you should look into media queries breakpoints for popular frameworks like bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should stop making the webpage responsive below to 320 pixels. Iphone5s has 320px width.

Answer (score 0):

[Material UI](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui) for example uses these lower limit breakpoints in pixel for declaring media queries:

```
  xs: 0,
  sm: 600,
  md: 960,
  lg: 1280,
  xl: 1920,
```

As @Gamers Agenda mentioned, you can stop at 320 pixels. Use these breakpoints as guidelines. If you want your page to be perfecttly responsive you might have to use more breakpoints but those five are reasonable to do in a given time and work perfectly well for most devices.